# Node Process hangs when saving many pubnub instances in memory

Tags: node.js, sockets, pubnub

When load testing the program i was using pubnub for creating some integration i sent around 2000 request and on each request pubnub instance was created with different pub,sub keys and subscription to channel and listeners added but after some time when there is network issue pubnub throws socket hang up error and the memory starts spiking and eventually process is killed though i am destroying pubnub object when there is failure in subscription.

```
class pubnub{
  private config;
  private pubnub;
  constructor(options){
    this.config = options
  }
  register(callback) {
    let timetoken = null;
    this.pubnub = new Pubnub({
      publish_key: options.publish_key,
      subscribe_key: options.subscribe_key,
      ssl: true,
      keepAlive: true
    });

    this.pubnub.addListener({
      message: function (m) {
        // console.log('----------------- ', m);
        if (timetoken !== m.timetoken) {
          timetoken = m.timetoken;
        }
      },
      status: function (m) {
        console.log(m);
          if (m && m.error === true) {
            this.pubnub.destroy(true);  
            return callback(m.errorData);
          }
          callback(null, true);
        }
      }
    });


    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: option.channels
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you may want to try to `pubnub.unsubscribeAll();` before running `pubnub.destroy()`.

Comment: Also, why are you creating PubNub multiple times and with different pub/sub keys? What's the requirement for this?

Comment: @StephenBlum did that i think it is due to machine's socket limit but doesn't make any sense as i am destroying pubnub instance will try something else.

Comment: @CraigConover for integrations

Comment: Integration? specifically though, why can't you init PubNub once? Why are you switching through different PubNub key sets? How many key sets and how frequently do you reuse the same key set? What I am getting at is can you create pubnub instances at app level and reuse them instead of create/destroy constantly? And is there a reason you must subscribe from the server side? It is something that is more of an edge use case rather than the typical. Provide some details on that requirement. Contact us at https://support.pubnub.com/ if you want to take this private and we'll post answer back here.

Comment: Integrations could be `IntegrationTests` or some sort of `Embedding`.